# ruby on rails reuse a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "recipes" table and an "ingredients" table. Each recipe "has_and_belong_to_many" ingredients and each ingredient "has_and_belong_to_many" recipes.

I want to add a link to the ingredient page: "show all recipes which contain this ingredient".

I wrote the following code in my ingredient controller:

```
def recipes
    @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    @recipes = @ingredient.recipes
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @recipes }
    end
end
```

My problem is that now it expects me to have a "recipes.html.erb" file under the "ingredients" view. 
I don't want to create a new view for this, I just want to use the same code I use in the "recipes" view (recipes/index.html.erb). 
How can I direct rails to this view?

(I'm using rails 3.x)

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
def recipes
    @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    @recipes = @ingredient.recipes
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render "recipes/index" }
       format.json { render json: @recipes }
    end
end
```

For details, please take a look at the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render